# Simple styling in Polymer 1.0

Tags: css, polymer

I'm trying to get to grips with Polymer 1.0 after doing a little work with 0.5. I'm struggling with what *should* be a very simple styling problem. I just can't seem to apply a style to a custom element.

Here is my element definition, `my-element.html`:

```html
<link rel="import" href="../core/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="my-element">
    <template><h1>Hello World</h1></template>
</dom-module>
<script>
Polymer({
    is: 'my-element',
});
</script>
```

And here is the main page using it, `index.html`:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="../core/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="my-element.html">
</head>
<body>
    <my-element></my-element>
</body>
</html>
```

This works fine... but now suppose I want to put a style on the instance of `my-element`. I add this to `index.html`:

```html
    <style>
        my-element {
            margin-top: 50px;
        }
    </style>
```

Nothing happens, no margin is added. Stangely the Elements inspector in Chrome doesn't seem to "see" the custom element, it looks like it's floating outside the page and doesn't enclose the elements contained within. See screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

I initially suspected a bug in Chrome but it's the same problem in Firefox.

Any help appreciated, many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting the attribute `is="custom-style"` on your style tag.

```
<style is="custom-style">
    ...
</style>
```

Also, by default an element will be displayed inline, but you can change this by applying a display property in your element `:host` style.

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <style>
    :host {display: block;}
  </style>
  <template>
    ...
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: Many thanks. Actually the `is=custom-style` was not necessary but `:host {display: block;}` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

because `my-element` is not a default DOM element, you should "enable" it, like those html5 shivs are doing it for older browser that dont understand the new html5 elements

[This tutorial should help you](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/)

```
var XFoo = document.registerElement('my-element');
document.body.appendChild(new XFoo());
```

The first argument to document.registerElement() is the element's tag name. The name must contain a dash (-). So for example, , , and  are all valid names, while  and  are not. This restriction allows the parser to distinguish custom elements from regular elements but also ensures forward compatibility when new tags are added to HTML.

The second argument is an (optional) object describing the element's prototype. This is the place to add custom functionality (e.g. public properties and methods) to your elements.

Comment: Unless you are using `Polymer.Class` in declaring an element, you do not need to register an element since Polymer automatically does this for you.